# Is my schematics correct? (Atmega328p for solenoids control)

Tags: arduino, mosfet, atmega, solenoid, mosfet-driver

Finally I finished the [second version](http://www.skeetty.com/schematics-servo.png) of my circuit which should control different solenoids.

You can view the large version [here](http://www.skeetty.com/schematics-servo.png).

[image]
In particular, this circuit should control 2 proportional solenoids and 7 ON/OFF solenoids.

The solenoids [parameters](http://www.skeetty.com/valve-proportional.jpg) are: 
V = 12Vcc, R = 3.7 Ohm, I = 1.80A

In order to prevent an atmega328p reset due to noise (like it happened in the first version), I added:

- an **optoisolator** [6N136](http://it.rs-online.com/webdocs/0779/0900766b80779703.pdf) for each output,
- a **MOSFET driver** [MCP1406](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20002019C.pdf) for each MOSFET
- an [isolated power supply THL-25](http://it.rs-online.com/webdocs/12a7/0900766b812a7208.pdf) to power up the atmega328p (main battery is an AGM Battery 12V, 200Ah).

As suggested in the [application note](http://www.tracopower.com/products/thl25-application.pdf) of its datasheet, I used an inductor L1-1UH with a capacitor for the THL-25 input. Is it OK?

In this way, I have two different grounds, **GND5 is the gnd for 12V**, while **GND is the ground for 5V** . I also added a **big 2200uF capacitor** between +12V and GND5 in order to avoid noise.
The capacitor **C5 100nF** is OK for the atmega328p?
I will place it very close to the atmega pins.

The output named "**OUT5/SERVO PWM**" should control a 12V, 4A RC servo.

Is there any error in my schematics?

Anything to improve?

The big C3 capacitor is enough for the filtering?

The circuit close to the isolated power supply is correct?

Can you help me, please?

I would like to improve my circuit, if possible.

Thank you for your support and your help!

---

**EDIT1:** I updated my schematics by adding the SERVO connections and pinout.
**EDIT2:** I changed the SERVO circuit by using a P-mosfet. This is the [SERVO schematics](http://www.skeetty.com/servo.png).

**EDIT3:**: This is the new [schematics](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?action=dlattach;topic=433294.0;attach=187606) for the servo controlling.

Comment: Have you read AVR042 yet?

Comment: I used the official connections for the atmega328p, as reported on the arduino documentation, too. Are they wrong?

Comment: Haven't actually looked yet. I'm multitasking ATM.

Comment: Why do you think you need to use both an optocoupler and a MOSFET driver here?

Comment: I just want to be sure that the atmega will be fully isolated from the high power lines.. is it not correct?

Comment: The gate of a NMOSFET is reasonably good at isolating the positive rail. For the negative rail there's star grounding.

Comment: I'm going to read something about the star grounding. Anyway, is it wrong to use optoisolator and mosfet driver like I did? Won't the circuit work properly in this case?

Comment: Looks line junction is missing on MCU PB4 <-> RC5 <-> ICSP? BTW there are too many junctions where you don't really need them... makes hard to read the schematic

Comment: Sorry flanker! I tried to follow the standard rules for the schematics designing to make it more easy to read. Unfortunately eagle automatically adds some junctioms

Comment: I updated the schematics by adding the missing junction. I tried to remove some junction, but Eagle don't allow me to do this. I added also the SERVO connections to make the schematics clearer.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

- The area in Yellow needs to be fixed as PWM will not work.
- Dont you want to put a cap on RESET to gnd for POR?
- How far are all the cable interfaces?
- What type of shielding do you need?
- Do you have a functional spec for immunity?
- Are you planning to do Susceptibility testing? Radiated Arc,  Impulse RF , Induction spikes etc.... if so what is your spec for dV/dt , dI/dt or field strengths for crosstalk from load to inputs etc.
- if you dont make a spec, how will you know it wont fail? or when it will fail

  - or if it is interface overkill./..\

It's like an architect who designs a bridge with elastomers and even tension supports and forgets about wind effects. If you dont define all the environmental risks, how can you say it passes?

Comment: I updated the schematics by adding the SERVO connection. I didn't understand your first three points and neither your drawing. Can you please let me know if the updated schematics is clearer? The servo is OK, now? Thank you!

Comment: there is an error in yellow, sorry, was trying to be funny,

Comment: Ki Servo pin 2 should go to D7-Anode if Servo is active LOW, otherwise Q6 is blocked by reverse biased D7

Comment: Thank you for you tips, Tony! I will fix this error immediately. Do you think the driver MCP will work fine with the mosfet and the optocoupler? I was thinking to add a ferrite bead close to the filter capacitor C3? Or is it not useful in this case?

Comment: I dont know if you verified dv/dt and aging margin for opto as LED declines in output with age.  why were you thinking ferrite for this?

Comment: The servo is active HIGH.. in this case I should connect pin2 to D7-anode anyway?

Comment: then circuit is wrong with a low side Nch switch, are you just copying a design blind?

Comment: yes, I already verified both the dv/dt and the CTR for the optocoupler and they should be OK with my parameters. I changed the SERVO circuit and I tried to use a P-mosfet. Can you tell me if the schematics for the SERVO is now correct, please? Sorry, I'm a beginner and I'm learning every day- >> [servo schematics](http://www.skeetty.com/servo.png) << I used the diode for the servo noise, I don't know if it is correct.

Comment: is servo  some low side switch with pullup or highside switch with R to gnd? if inductive cable, high side turn off makes a negative spike so D7 cathode moves from V+ to Servo PWM input to clamp neg. spike to -0.7, , if low side switch with pullup move as indicated in my dwg

Comment: Thanks again Tony. The servo is active HIGH, I studied a little bit my problem and I thought that controlling a 12V servo with a MOSFET and an IC MOSFET DRIVER it is too much. I redraw the >>[circuit](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?action=dlattach;topic=433294.0;attach=187606) << by using only the 6N136 optocoupler. I tried to hook it up to consider the non-inverting situation. I don't know if it is correct or not since I don't have experience in electronics. Please help me. I could not vote your answer since my score is too low.

Comment: https://www.google.ca/search?q=high+side+switch&client=safari&hl=en-ca&prmd=isvn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjlsK3Qr7XQAhWI3YMKHRyxD8gQ_AUIBygB&biw=1024&bih=649

Comment: This is the [new schematics](http://www.skeetty.com/schematics-servo.png) with the high-side switch configuration for the servo connection. It has a voltage divider in order to obtain +5V in the case the servo signal only accepts +5V voltage. (The servo manufacturer said me that I can also use +12V). I placed C1 and C21 as filtering for servo noise even if I think the servo should already include some filtering methods inside its electronics.

Comment: Tony, I would like to vote for your answer, but I still need 1 point to be able to vote. Sorry.